# what is shell_add_cmd, is it for linux to add command?

Tags: linux

I saw the function of `shell_add_cmd`, is this a `linux` function to add command? And how to use it? It is very hard to find information about this function on the internet, can someone help on it?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: the programming language is C

Comment: Please provide more context. Where did you see this command? Why do you need to know what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be a Linux command. It's from RLRL, apparently a videogame: https://github.com/jabb/rlrl/blob/master/shell.c#L336

Comment: I've also seen it in erlang and other: http://erlang.googlecode.com/svn-history/r39/trunk/erts/etc/ose/erl.exec.c

Comment: what is this extactly? are there anyone knows about it?